# Reverse Engineering Z3 SMT solver solutions

Tags: reverse-engineering, z3, smt, z3py

I am using Z3 named SMT solver to generate a new set of random numbers from a given vector under some constraints. I am doing this in order to hide my input stream. The corresponding code can be found below:

```
from z3 import *
import sys
import io
import math


X0 = Real('X0')
X1 = Real('X1')
X2 = Real('X2')
X3 = Real('X3')
X4 = Real('X4')
X5 = Real('X5')
X6 = Real('X6')
X7 = Real('X7')
X8 = Real('X8')
X9 = Real('X9')
X10 = Real('X10')
X11 = Real('X11')
X12 = Real('X12')
X13 = Real('X13')
X14 = Real('X14')

DistinctParameter = [Distinct(X0 , X1 , X2 , X3 , X4 , X5 , X6 , X7 , X8 , X9 , X10 , X11 , X12 , X13 , X14 )]

maxPossibleValue = max(InputStream)

AggregateValue = 0
for x in InputStream:
    AggregateValue = AggregateValue + float(x)

S_Con_Comparison1 = [(X0 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison2 = [(X1 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison3 = [(X2 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison4 = [(X3 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison5 = [(X4 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison6 = [(X5 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison7 = [(X6 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison8 = [(X7 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison9 = [(X8 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison10 = [(X9 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison11 = [(X10 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison12 = [(X11 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison13 = [(X12 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison14 = [(X13 < maxPossibleValue)] 
S_Con_Comparison15 = [(X14 < maxPossibleValue)] 


S_Con_Comparison = S_Con_Comparison1 + S_Con_Comparison2 + S_Con_Comparison3 + S_Con_Comparison4 + S_Con_Comparison5 + S_Con_Comparison6 + S_Con_Comparison7 + S_Con_Comparison8 + S_Con_Comparison9 + S_Con_Comparison10 + S_Con_Comparison11 + S_Con_Comparison12 + S_Con_Comparison13 + S_Con_Comparison14 + S_Con_Comparison15

S_Con = [( X0 + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11 + X12 + X13 + X14 == AggregateValue)]

Solve = S_Con + S_Con_Comparison + DistinctParameter

s = Solver()

s.add(Solve)


x = Reals('x')
i = 0 
output =[0] * len(InputStream)

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    for d in m.decls():
        location = int((repr(d).replace("X","")))
        x=round(float(m[d].numerator_as_long())/float(m[d].denominator_as_long()),5)
        output[location]= x

print(output)
```

Each of the values of the input stream can be taken from a possible set of size 2^25. As per my understanding, the only way to find the input stream is to do a brute force on the resulted stream. Given this circumstances, I want to know if it is possible to reverse engineer the input stream from the corresponding output stream.

Comment: Please post a simplified version of your code (perhaps only a few values?) and something that people can run on their own. The above is not a self-contained program. See here for guidelines on how to post to stack-overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The thing to consider is: What makes you think the input stream is uniquely determined from your constraints? I see nothing in your description that would guarantee that. So, while you'd find an input-stream, it'd probably not be uniquely determined. You really have to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on an SMT solver to generate anything even remotely *random* since they tend to be rather deterministic.. the randomness of an SMT solver is generally limited to an old-fashioned pseudo-random generator which is normally initialized with the same seed each time so as to make it easier to reproduce actual bugs.

Comment: Is your input stream always larger or equal zero? Is it acceptable for the output stream to include negative values? can the attacker fiddle with your python script? The `float -> Real -> float` passages are going to introduce tiny but unavoidable errors.. are these acceptable for your application?

Comment: Notice that the lack of randomness exposes your approach to the use of rainbow tables. At the very minimum, you should set the initial *random seed* of the solver to a truly random value. This might actually not be helpful in your case, because while the pseudo-random generator certainly affects the SAT engine (AFAIK), I doubt that it also affects the model generation routine within the LRA-Solver. This might be easy to verify for you, since the source code is available online.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to get a decent "random" sample out of the box for precisely those reasons. You'd need an extra mechanism on top of SMT to sample the space according to some notion of "uniformity," which isn't what an SMT solver designed to do out of the box.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. The input stream has a constant length of 15. I have a simulator which is constantly generating a input stream of size 15 from a set of size 2^25 of positive real numbers. later I am using this stream as an input to my algorithm. The input stream and the algorithm is available to any attacker. I want to hide this stream from being identified from the attacker's point of view. The algorithm which is working on the input stream will also give the same results if the total sum of the stream remains unaltered.

Comment: So, I am using the Z3 to generate a new stream that will keep the summation over the original input stream constant. The resulted output stream will contain only positive real numbers. The algorithm used to alter the input stream can be seen by the attacker but the attacker do not have the access to modify or fiddle that. Given this scenario, I want to know if it is possible for the attacker to identify the original input stream from the resulted modified stream.

Comment: @SumanaBagchi I don't see any constraint saying that all `X_i` must be positive in your source code. Are all the values in the **original** input stream also guaranteed to be positive? Are you **sure** that the result of `float -> Real -> float` conversion does not **change** due to approximations in the conversions and accumulated errors the value of the aggregated sum? if the original input stream is `A B C` and my reverse-engineering approach yields me `B C A`, would that be considered a successful attack? is `+` supposed to be a conjunction in the `Solve` constraint?

Comment: Hi Sir, all the values in the original input stream is guaranteed to be positive. The aggregated sum will change slightly due to the approximation and type conversion. But it will not have any significant effect on the future executions. Simultaneously, a successful attack will get back the original stream as it is. As per your example if the input stream is A B C then if the reverse-engineering approach gives the B C A, it will not be considered as a successful attack. And the "+" operator is a conjunction in the solve constraint.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to include the information you put in the comments (these may be deleted by S.O. at any time) and also to clarify the question in the same way you did in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, SMT solvers should not be entrusted with the task of generating *truly random* models. Having said this, it doesn't look like you need such property to be guaranteed for your application.

---

I fixed your model so as to impose `X_i >= 0`, since this is a requirement in the comments.

```py
from z3 import *
import sys
import io
import math

def obfuscate(input_stream):
    X_list = [Real('X_{0}'.format(idx)) for idx in range(0, len(input_stream))]
    assert len(X_list) == len(input_stream)

    max_input_value = max(input_stream)
    aggregate_value = sum(input_stream)

    distinct_cs = Distinct(X_list)
    lower_cs = [(0 <= Xi) for Xi in X_list]
    upper_cs = [(Xi < max_input_value) for Xi in X_list]
    same_sum_cs = (Sum(X_list) == aggregate_value)

    s = Solver()
    s.add(distinct_cs)
    s.add(lower_cs)
    s.add(upper_cs)
    s.add(same_sum_cs)

    status = s.check()

    if status == sat:
        r_ret = []
        fp_ret = []

        m = s.model()
        for Xi in X_list:
            r_value = m.eval(Xi)
            r_ret.append(r_value)

            num = r_value.numerator_as_long()
            den = r_value.denominator_as_long()

            fp_value = round(float(num) / float(den), 5)
            fp_ret.append(fp_value)

        return input_stream, aggregate_value, "sat", r_ret, fp_ret, sum(fp_ret)

    else:
        return input_stream, aggregate_value, "unsat", None, None, None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Same-value inputs are all unsat")
    print(obfuscate([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]))
    print(obfuscate([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
    print(obfuscate([2.0, 2.0, 2.0]))

    print("\nRe-ordering input does not change output")
    print(obfuscate([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
    print(obfuscate([1.0, 3.0, 2.0]))
    print(obfuscate([3.0, 2.0, 1.0]))
    print("")
    print(obfuscate([0.1, 0.0, 0.0]))
    print(obfuscate([0.0, 0.1, 0.0]))
    print(obfuscate([0.0, 0.0, 0.1]))

    print("\nSame-sum input do not necessarily map to the same outputs")
    print(obfuscate([0.1, 0.9, 2.0]))
    print(obfuscate([1.1, 0.1, 1.8]))

    print("\nSame outputs may result from different inputs")
    print(obfuscate([0.6, 1.3, 1.1]))
    print(obfuscate([1.3, 0.7, 1.0]))
```

The output is:

```py
Same-value inputs are all unsat
([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0.0, 'unsat', None, None, None)
([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 3.0, 'unsat', None, None, None)
([2.0, 2.0, 2.0], 6.0, 'unsat', None, None, None)

Re-ordering input does not change output
([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 6.0, 'sat', [5/2, 11/4, 3/4], [2.5, 2.75, 0.75], 6.0)
([1.0, 3.0, 2.0], 6.0, 'sat', [5/2, 11/4, 3/4], [2.5, 2.75, 0.75], 6.0)
([3.0, 2.0, 1.0], 6.0, 'sat', [5/2, 11/4, 3/4], [2.5, 2.75, 0.75], 6.0)

([0.1, 0.0, 0.0], 0.1, 'sat', [1/30, 1/15, 0], [0.03333, 0.06667, 0.0], 0.09999999999999999)
([0.0, 0.1, 0.0], 0.1, 'sat', [1/30, 1/15, 0], [0.03333, 0.06667, 0.0], 0.09999999999999999)
([0.0, 0.0, 0.1], 0.1, 'sat', [1/30, 1/15, 0], [0.03333, 0.06667, 0.0], 0.09999999999999999)

Same-sum input do not necessarily map to the same outputs
([0.1, 0.9, 2.0], 3.0, 'sat', [4/3, 5/3, 0], [1.33333, 1.66667, 0.0], 3.0)
([1.1, 0.1, 1.8], 3.0, 'sat', [7/5, 8/5, 0], [1.4, 1.6, 0.0], 3.0)

Same outputs may result from different inputs
([0.6, 1.3, 1.1], 3.0, 'sat', [23/20, 49/40, 5/8], [1.15, 1.225, 0.625], 3.0)
([1.3, 0.7, 1.0], 3.0, 'sat', [23/20, 49/40, 5/8], [1.15, 1.225, 0.625], 3.0)
```

This simple example allows us to make the following observations:

- the output is determined by the values in input, but it is not affected by their order
- the obfuscation procedure can be sensitive to variations in the input stream

Therefore, even if an **attacker** attempts to use **rainbow tables** to find the potential input [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) that generated an output sequence, they still cannot find the exact order of the values in the input stream.

Let's disregard the fact that building such *rainbow tables* is impractical due to the large number of input sequences of size `15` that can be generated with
a pool of `2^25` candidate values (a loose upper-bound would be `2^375`), and assume that we have a way to access it efficiently.

Given an output sequence `O`, generated with `obfuscate()`, we can look for a match `M` inside our *rainbow table*, where `M` is a list of [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) that, when used as input, would result in the same output `O`. Let `M[i]` be the `i`-th input set in `M` containing `n` elements, each with multiplicity `m_i`. Then the number of possible permutations of `M[i]` is (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)):

[image]

In the simplest scenario in which every value in the input stream is different from the others, there are up to `15! = 1.307.674.368.000` permutations for each candidate solution `M[i]` in the match `M`. *In your application, would the attacker have the time to try all of them?*